# Error in mongodb export in node,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I was trying to connect mongodb using node.js. I stumbled on a problem.
I am getting   require(...).pure is not a function error . I tried to use the exact code from this site  "https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html"
My code is given below.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
Code = require('mongodb').Code,
BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
assert = require('assert');

var uri = "mongodb://sa:psvitagamer5@cluster0-shard-00-00-
 tpfog.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-
  tpfog.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-
  tpfog.mongodb.net:27017/myNodeDb?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-
  0&authSource=admin";


 MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {

   var collection = db.collection("userCollection");

    collection.insert({hello:'world_no_safe'});

   // Wait for a second before finishing up, to ensure we have written 
     the item to disk
   setTimeout(function() {

  // Fetch the document
   collection.findOne({hello:'world_no_safe'}, function(err, item) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      assert.equal('world_no_safe', item.hello);
      db.close();
   })
   }, 100);
  //db.close();
});
```

Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Out of topic but I suggest you to use mongoose

Comment: Where do you use `Db` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That documentation is not well written nor tested, `pure()` is in `mongodb-core` module

You should install `mongodb-core` and use:

```
BSON = require('mongodb-core').BSON;
```

2. As I can see you (and that documentation) are not using `BSON` at all, you should remove that.

Comment: require('mongodb-core').BSON works but require('mongodb-core').BSON.pure().BSON gives the same error . Is 'require('mongodb-core').BSON' only required?

Comment: Like I said in second point, you are not using any `BSON` functions, just remove that require line and you should be ok